# To grep the value of row and column from the output of a command in unix

Tags: bash, awk, grep, solaris

I need to get the value of "Boot Environment Name", "Active Now", "Active On Reboot" from the output of "lustatus" command in Solaris, to figure out if there is any switch in the boot environment.

I'll store the value of Active boot environment in a file, and check if there is any change in boot environment during an upgrade, to perform some operations.

Output of lustatus command will be like this:

```
bash-3.2# /usr/sbin/lustatus
Boot Environment           Is       Active Active    Can    Copy
Name                       Complete Now    On Reboot Delete Status
-------------------------- -------- ------ --------- ------ ----------
d10                        yes      yes    yes       no     -
d70                        yes      no     no        yes    -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk

```
/usr/sbin/lustatus  | awk 'NR>3&&$3=="yes"{print $1}'
```

Comment: +1 but I recommend generous use of spaces for more readable style, like this: `'NR > 3 && $3 == "yes" {print $1}'`

Answer (score 3):

> how can i put a condition check for the value of "Active now" as
>   "yes", then print only the "Boot Environment Name" in awk command?

this line would do:

```
yourCmd|awk '$3=="yes"&&$0=$1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this `awk` example will help;

```
/usr/sbin/lustatus | tail -n 2 | awk '{print $1 " " $3 " " $4}'

d10 yes yes
d70 no no
```

Comment: you can eliminate `tail` by using NR>3 in `awk`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
But how can i put a condition check for the value of "Active now" as "yes", then print only the "Boot Environment Name" in awk command?